# Cross-browser Grid system in HTML

Tags: css, cross-browser

I want to apply a **gridding system** to my project, but the resource I got was applicable only to **IE8-10**, the grid doesn't work fine on other browsers.

I want the grid to display efficiently on **Chrome, Opera, and Firefox**(Cross-browser).

This the css code:

```
body{
-ms-grid-columns: ;
-ms-grid-rows: ;
}
body{
  display: -ms-grid;
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You cannot magically make browsers support new features.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a working implementation of CSS3 Grid Layout for Webkit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015928/is-there-a-working-implementation-of-css3-grid-layout-for-webkit)

Comment: @SLaks you cannot magically assume everyone knows everything, exactly the way you know it. the question does make it ok to assume the developer will have alot of questions in regards to browsers/browser support, etc. fyi, you can magically make browsers support new features, you just have to know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

This has already been answered [on Stack Overflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015928/is-there-a-working-implementation-of-css3-grid-layout-for-webkit).

The correct answer is by [thirtydot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405015/thirtydot) on there.  to paraphrase to bring that answer up-to-date and more relevant to your specific question:

---

[Grid Layout](http://caniuse.com/css-grid) has very poor support - the declarations you're using that start `-ms` are Microsoft vendor-specific and not supported by other browsers.

Webkit (the engine behind Chrome and Safari) has been working on an implementation as [seen here](https://bugs.webkit.org/showdependencytree.cgi?id=60731&hide_resolved=0) but it's still incomplete and uses slightly-different syntax:

```
.gridWithFixed {
    display: -webkit-grid;
    -webkit-grid-columns: 7px 11px;
    -webkit-grid-rows: 17px 2px;
}
```

So, right now there isn't a way of implementing your CSS in a way that will work outside of nightly browser builds and IE10.

As an alternative, [Flexbox](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) has decent support (including IE10). So, the best you can do is use Flexbox instead.

Comment: Thanks @john, but itried this method that you used above but no difference.

Comment: Hi @Kindoprecy.  That's precisely the point of my answer: the code I included was being considered for inclusion in Webkit but isn't yet complete.  You may find support in the nightlies but it won't work for production.  As I mentioned: there isn't any cross-browser way of using Grid Layout, you'd be far better off using Flexbox or restructuring your markup to remove the requirement.

Comment: Actually, Flexbox has questionable support thanks to the Mozilla team dragging its feet when it comes to providing a complete implementation.

Answer (score 1):

css3 support cross-browser/platform is quite pathetic at the moment.
flexbox is an option, although with its limited support, @ least in legacy browsers, it's not a knockout. this depends on what you are supporting: how many browsers, browser versions, user agents, etc.? are there a lot of legacy or "non-modern" browsers in that list? then i would avoid flexbox.

i would use [960gs](http://960.gs) or [unsemantic](http://unsemantic.com), cross-browser grid layout libraries. unsemantic is the successor, but they are both versatile, and very light-weight.